# Need to use gcc for computer science I class on C++, having trouble getting started

Tags: linux, c++, gcc

This is the recommendation from my instructor on software for Linux (since the required software, Visual Studio 2017, is not available for Linux (I have Mint):
**2) If you are a LINUX user, I will accept homework developed using the open source gcc compiler from the Free Software Foundation.**

However, the instructor does not provide any help with the software installation process. As I am new to both programming and Linux, I am needing some help. I only have experience with using Microsoft Azure notebooks when was learning Python, and only now am getting experienced with PyCharm, other than that, I have no idea about software for coding.

I am pretty sure that I have installed gcc correctly using the terminal just now. (If this provides any confirmation on my installing it correctly, if I go to the 'Software Manager' and type in 'gcc', it shows a green check mark, indicating it's installed).

***How do I use gcc now to practice C++? How can I save the codes so can upload it for homework? Do I need to install anything else, or do I just use gcc from the terminal?***

Comment: If the instructor provides more help with Windows, then perhaps that's a good place to start?

Comment: Visual Studio Code does support your operating system.  If you are familar with Visual Studio I suggest using that, instead of struggling with trying to compile code manually, entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

### Installation

In addition to `gcc`, also install `g++` . It is the name of the GCC C++ compiler.

### Text editor

Then to start practising C++, open a simple [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) and write a C++ program like this one:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Save this text in a file named  **hello.cpp**  (the `.cpp` extension means C++).

### Terminal

Then open a terminal, navigate to the directory where your file **hello.cpp** is stored, using the `cd` command. For instance, if you saved the file in the directory called `/home/elizabeth/Desktop` , enter this command:

```
cd /home/elizabeth/Desktop
```

After that, to compile your program, execute the following command:

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

If your program is correct, `g++` does not complain and generates an executable program named **`a.out`** . You cannot read this file, it is machine language.

Finally, execute that executable by entering its name as a command:

```
./a.out
```

And you should see `Hello World!` appear in the terminal.

Note: the name of the executable file is **`a.out`** but to execute it, you need to write a **dot**, followed by a **slash**, followed by its name **`a.out`**

Comment: @Elizabeth, this is a good answer to get you started.  But if everything in it is new to you, consider Ramhound's comment on the question.  Any course of this nature will be designed to be a challenge if the only thing you're learning is the course content.  If you are not already familiar with Linux, and will be on your own with the supporting software, the course will be much harder, require much more of your time, and put you at a disadvantage compared with the rest of the class.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the issue is just that Visual Studio is not in the Mint repository, you can download the Linux version [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) (the .deb version).  Right click on the package after download, and you should see an option to open/install it with the package manager.